# How to say an event happens in the same room with another event that we know

Tags: grammar, usage

Let's assume we have two events like lectures. I know lecture A is given at ROOM1. I know lecture B is given at ROOM1, too (at a different time). Someone came and ask me "Where is the Lecture 2". Is my below statement correct?:

> The same place where LectureA happens?

Another option is:

> It is in the same room as LectureA

I have seen two examples in macmillandictionary.com. The first one is:

> Animals feel pain the same as we do.

and the second one is

> We were staying at the same hotel as our parents.

Can you explain why in the first sentence the verb do was added whereas in the second one there is no verb at the end of sentence? I mean, could it have written as We were staying at the same hotel as our parents were staying

Comment: Could you explain what your doubt is with these sentences. I don't want to write a one word answer.

Comment: @JamesK Sure. In the first sentence, my concern is on the verb. I am not sure if 'happens' is the best choice there. In the second one, I feel like I need to describe it more by writing more after LectureA but I don't know what exactly I should write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a word like "happens", so your second sentence is correct.

But if you use "where", then a word phrase like "happens" or "is held" is necessary.

> It's in the same room as where Lecture A happens/occurs/{is held}.

Normally I'd prefer the shorter:

> In the same room as Lecture A.

The verb in these contexts can be omitted if it is understood from the context:

> We were staying at the same hotel as our parents (were staying).
>
> I sleep in the same room as my sister.

This implies "as my sister sleeps in" (or perhaps "as the room in which my sister sleeps"). We would normally *omit* the verb to avoid repetition.

If you want to say something else you can specify the verb.

> I sleep in the same room as the one my sister studies in.

You can also add a verb for clarity or emphasis

> Animals feel pain the same way as we do!

(slightly more emphatic than "the same way as us")

And notice the pronoun choice in that last example. I changed from
 "... we do", to "... us". If there is no verb, then don't use the subject form.

Comment: Please make sure you include *all* relevant research in your question, and not in a comment on an answer.  This information would have made your question better.